# JavaScript Get value (text) in all aria-labels in an array and add value to a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to get the text value for each aria-label in a webpage.

I can get the elements and id/class where there is an existing aria-label

```
var labelArray = document.querySelectorAll("*[aria-label]");
```

I don't know how to iterate through the array using a for loop and then write the aria-label values to a list. I can get all the attributes and values where there is an aria-label, but not just the text of the aria-label.

```
var labelArray = document.querySelectorAll("*[aria-label]");
var labelText = labelArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < labelText; i++) {
    console.log(labelArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: [querySeletorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (array-like but not an Array) that has a [*forEach* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). Consider `labelArray.forEach(node => console.log(node.getAttribute('aria-label')))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I've added [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to your loop to get the value of the `aria-label` attribute, before pushing that value into an array name `list`.

```js
const list = []
const labels = document.querySelectorAll("*[aria-label]");
const labelCount = labels.length;

for (let i = 0; i < labelCount; i++) {
    const labelText = labels[i].getAttribute('aria-label')
    list.push(labelText);
}


console.log(list);
```

```html
<p aria-label="test"></p>
<p aria-label="test2"></p>
<p aria-label="test3"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good use case for using `Array.from()` and it's internal mapping function

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll("*[aria-label]");
const list = Array.from(labels, (el, i) => el.getAttribute('aria-label'));

console.log(list);
```

```html
<p aria-label="test"></p>
<p aria-label="test2"></p>
<p aria-label="test3"></p>
```